# Subject: ssh-copy-id postgres@secondaryserverip is not working for postgres user (checked with root and any other user it's working) )

Tags: linux, postgresql, ssh, scp

I have installed two ubuntu server as Linux primary and Linux secondary.

I Have installed shh on both server and allow network and permissions.

when I tried to ssh-copy  Linux primary server to Linux secondary I got permission denied issue,

```
ssh-copy-id postgres@secondaryserverip
```

and I tried most of all sites and tried everything it's not working.

Note:  I CREATED USER/ROOT  AND TRIED COPYING  IT'S WORKING.EXCEPT POSTGRES USER.

Comment: As the man page says, "presumably using a login password, so password authentication should be enabled"  Is it?  it generally isn't for the user named postgres.